# как сделать юнит тест консольного приложения на C++ в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2017

не совсем понимаю, как делать юнит-тесты в Visual Studio 2019. В 2017 версии был отдельный проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в 2019 не могу его найти... Есть ли какая-то замена или откуда его можно скачать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В окне "Создание проекта" в начальном окне вы можете увидеть надпись "Установка других средств и компонентов". Нажмите на неё. После нажмите на "Отдельные компоненты" и напишите в поисковой строке "Адаптер тестов". Установите галочку возле "Адаптер тестов для Google Test/Boost.Test" (Можете всё вместе - они вместе тратят ~50 мб памяти). После нажмите "Изменить". Обновите ide если это возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания юнит-тестов в Visual Studio никакой специальный проект не требуется. Создавайте обычное консольное приложение. Обозреватель тестов автоматически распознает тесты всех поддерживаемых форматов.